# How can I test FeignClient unmarshalling?

Tags: json, spring-boot, unmarshalling

I have a FeignClient and a golden JSON that gonna be unmarshalled into custom `MyResponse`.

How can I test that marshalling to make sure `MyResponse` is designed correctly? Like:

```
String jsonText = "{...}";
MyResponse response = unmarshal(jsonText, MyResponse.class);
// verify the response
```

The client:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

@FeignClient("xxx")
public interface MyApiClient extends MyApi {
}

@RequestMapping("/my-api")
public interface MyApi {
    @PostMapping(value = "/method", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    MyResponse method(MyRequest request);
}
```

P.S. Spring Boot 1.5

Comment: What are using for `unmarshal` method? could you post it? So if you want to test your `feign client endpoint` with other type of object then you might use `ResponseEntity<MyResponse>` and check if your response entity has what you want.

Comment: The `unmarshal()` method is what I'm looking for.